# Passing F keys to Emulated Telnet session in Powershell (TCP)

Tags: function, powershell, tcp, key, telnet

I have figured out a way to connect to a telnet server using powershell. The script allows to create a tcp socket type connections and pass commands.

Basically, I use System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
System.IO.StreamWriter
and then a sequence of WriteLine and Flush methods.

I have no problem passing regular ascii type lines using WriteLine.
But how do I pass on the F3 key.

F3 has no ASCII code, and I don't know what byte sequence is sent to telnet when I hit F3. I need F3 to do certain tasks in the telnet session.

Any assistance is highly appreciated. Here is an example of my code:

```
$x = [char]114 + [char]189 <-- F3 key ???????????????????


Function Get-Telnet
{   Param (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)],
    [string]$RemoteHost = "HostnameOrIPAddress",
    [string]$Port = "23",
    [int]$WaitTime = 6000,
    [string]$OutputPath = ""
)
#Attach to the remote device, setup streaming requirements
$Socket = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($RemoteHost, $Port)
If ($Socket)
{   $Stream = $Socket.GetStream()
    $Writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($Stream)
    $Buffer = New-Object System.Byte[] 1024 
    $Encoding = New-Object System.Text.AsciiEncoding

    #Now start issuing the commands
    $Writer.WriteLine([char]08)
    $Writer.Flush()
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $WaitTime
    $Writer.WriteLine("TA")
    $Writer.Flush()
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $WaitTime
    $Writer.WriteLine("12345")
    $Writer.Flush()
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $WaitTime
    $Writer.Write($x)
    $Writer.Flush()


    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds ($WaitTime * 4)
    $Result = ""
    #Save all the results
    While($Stream.DataAvailable) 
    {   $Read = $Stream.Read($Buffer, 0, 1024) 
        $Result += ($Encoding.GetString($Buffer, 0, $Read))
    }
}
Else     
{   $Result = "Unable to connect to host: $($RemoteHost):$Port"
}
#Done, now save the results to a file
$Result | Out-File $OutputPath
}


Get-Telnet -RemoteHost "localhost" -OutputPath c:\windows\temp\telnetlog.imp
```

---

*UPDATE:*

---

Updated code to enter F3, see below. still F3 not received by telnet session. Every other key works. F3 basically logs off the telnet session for this specific telnet app.

```
$y = "\033[13~"
$z = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($y)
$z
Function Get-Telnet
{   Param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [String[]]$Commands = @([char]08,"TA","12345","N","N","N"),
        [string]$RemoteHost = "HostnameOrIPAddress",
        [string]$Port = "23",
        [int]$WaitTime = 6000,
        [string]$OutputPath = "\\server\share\switchbackup.txt"
        )
        #Attach to the remote device, setup streaming requirements
        $Socket = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($RemoteHost, $Port)
        If ($Socket)
        {   $Stream = $Socket.GetStream()
            $Writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($Stream)
            $BinWriter = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($stream)
            $Buffer = New-Object System.Byte[] 1024 
            $Encoding = New-Object System.Text.AsciiEncoding

            #Now start issuing the commands
            $Writer.WriteLine([char]08)
            $Writer.Flush()
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $WaitTime
            $Writer.WriteLine("TA")
            $Writer.Flush()
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $WaitTime
            $Writer.Write("12345")
            $Writer.Flush()
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $WaitTime
            $BinWriter.Write($z)
   #        $Writer.Write($z)
        $BinWriter.Flush()
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
            $BinWriter.Write($z)
            $BinWriter.Flush()
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500       

            #All commands issued, but since the last command is usually going to be
            #the longest let's wait a little longer for it to finish
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds ($WaitTime * 4)
            $Result = ""
            #Save all the results
            While($Stream.DataAvailable) 
            {   $Read = $Stream.Read($Buffer, 0, 1024) 
                $Result += ($Encoding.GetString($Buffer, 0, $Read))
            }
        }
        Else     
        {   $Result = "Unable to connect to host: $($RemoteHost):$Port"
        }
        #Done, now save the results to a file
       $Result | Out-File $OutputPath
    }

    #Get-Telnet -RemoteHost localhost -Commands "TA" -OutputPath c:\windows             \temp\telnetlog.imp
   Get-Telnet -RemoteHost "localhost" -OutputPath c:\windows\temp\telnetlog.imp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This FIXED it. I Can send F3 through this script to a telnet session.
Notice the Bytes for $z and I closed the socket at the bottom.

I had to use wireshark to figure out he bytes.

```
[Byte[]] $z = 0x1b, 0x4f, 0x52


Function Get-Telnet
{   Param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [String[]]$Commands = @([char]08,"TA","12345","N","N","N"),
        [string]$RemoteHost = "HostnameOrIPAddress",
        [string]$Port = "23",
        [int]$WaitTime = 6000,
        [string]$OutputPath = "\\server\share\switchbackup.txt"
        )
    #Attach to the remote device, setup streaming requirements
    $Socket = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($RemoteHost, $Port)
If ($Socket)
{   $Stream = $Socket.GetStream()
    $Writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($Stream)
    $BinWriter = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($stream)
    $Buffer = New-Object System.Byte[] 1024 
    $Encoding = New-Object System.Text.AsciiEncoding

    #Now start issuing the commands
    $Writer.WriteLine([char]08)
    $Writer.Flush()
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $WaitTime
    $Writer.WriteLine("TA")
    $Writer.Flush()
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $WaitTime
    $Writer.Write("12345")
    $Writer.Flush()
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $WaitTime
    $BinWriter.Write($z)
    $BinWriter.Flush()
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $WaitTime     
    $BinWriter.Write($z)
    $BinWriter.Flush()
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $WaitTime 

    #All commands issued, but since the last command is usually going to be
    #the longest let's wait a little longer for it to finish
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds ($WaitTime * 4)
    $Result = ""
    #Save all the results
    While($Stream.DataAvailable) 
    {   $Read = $Stream.Read($Buffer, 0, 1024) 
        $Result += ($Encoding.GetString($Buffer, 0, $Read))
    }
    $Socket.Close()
}
Else     
{   $Result = "Unable to connect to host: $($RemoteHost):$Port"
}


#Done, now save the results to a file

$Result | Out-File $OutputPath

}

Get-Telnet -RemoteHost "localhost" -OutputPath c:\windows\temp\telnetlog.imp
```

Answer (score 0):

Like control-key combos (ctrl-v, ctrl-c and so on), there are special sequences which can be sent to accomplish the task.

A good summary can be found [here](https://jscape.kayako.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/5), other websites show the same results.

However, I am not sure whether this is a internetwork standard or implementation/shell dependent, since I found nothing regarding this in the RFCs.

Please note that F3 is used by the windows cmd (and the powershell) to paste the last executed command, so you have to invoke the transmission of F3 otherwise.

Comment: This is good info, but I'm still having trouble sending the F3 byte sequence.

    # \033[13~
    $x = [char]92 + [char]48 + [char]51 + [char]51 + [char]91 + [char]49 + [char]51 + [char]126 ; 

    If ($Socket)
    {   $Stream = $Socket.GetStream() ;
        $Writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($Stream) ;
        $Buffer = New-Object System.Byte[] 1024 ;
        $Encoding = New-Object System.Text.AsciiEncoding ;

        #Now start issuing the commands
  $Writer.Writeline($x) ;
  $Writer.Flush() ;
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500 ;

Comment: Could you update the question with the new code and a description of the problem which occours now?

Comment: still scratching my head on this one. Not sure why its so hard to send f3 bytes, and why the above wont work. I noticed instead is just write those characters to the terminal rather than execute the bytes......